# Ничего не выводится после цикла while

Tags: c#

Писал в VS Code. Ошибку не выдаёт, однако ничего в консоль не выводится. В онлайн компиляторе показало ошибку, но я так и не понял в чём она. Я пока учу только основы C# так что не ругайте.

Код :

```
static void Main()
{
    byte i = 2;

    while (i >= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element : {0}", i);
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у тебя в условии написано "если i больше или равно 10 ", в то время как оно меньше (2). То есть оно делает все ровно так как ты его попросил сделать.

Answer (score 3):

В условии цикла вы поставили `i >= 10` (i больше или равно 10), а у вас `i=2`. Поменяйте знак неравенства на меньше или равно (`<=`).